# Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (31500, 784)

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am new to CNNs and am working on/using the MNIST dataset. After splitting the data to train and test sets, I needed to use 'ImageDataGenerator'. The code I used is the same code on the Keras API site.

The shapes are as below:

```
print(X_train.shape,
X_test.shape
,y_train.shape
,y_test.shape)
```

```
(31500, 784) (10500, 784) (31500,) (10500,)
```

But I suddenly faced a ValueError. Here is my code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

datagen.fit(X_train)
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (31500, 784)
```

How can I handle this error? Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fit` method of `ImageDataGenerator` expects an input with four dimensions (`n_samples, height, width, n_channels`). The data you are providing only has two dimension, i.e. `n_samples, height*width*n_channels`. Try reshaping the data before using the `fit` method as follows:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

datagen.fit(X_train.reshape(31500, 28, 28, 1))
```

Comment: It works. Thank you.